# ManyChat integration on Wordpress: This plugin requires the use of the JavaScript SDK and XFBML

Tags: wordpress, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm using ManyChat for Facebook messenger bot integrated on my WordPress website. However, I keep on getting this error:

"This plugin requires the use of the JavaScript SDK and XFBML."

The problem only occurred when the user IS NOT LOGGED IN to facebook, so need to click "Log in to Facebook button" first. After clicking the button, it will redirect to facebook log in. Once logged in, the FB window is automatically closed and back to the website again. However, the widget button will print error instead of the messenger icon. Once clicked on the error link, it will show this warning.

However, if the user already logged in to Facebook, there's no problem at all.

I've searched through the web however, most of the answers only applied to facebook SDK. As I'm using ManyChat now, I've removed the facebook SDK script, and just apply the many chat's scripts to all headers using a WordPress plugin. The code as below:

```
<script src="//widget.manychat.com/id-here.js" async="async"></script>
```

I really appreciate any help :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“As I'm using ManyChat now, I've removed the facebook SDK script”_ - did it say in the instructions that you were supposed to do that? Because the error message rather sounds as if it expects you to embed the JS SDK yourself.

Comment: I did that. Sorry. I included the script again into my code. If i exclude the sdk script, the bot wont appear. However, this error still persist. I tried on other website too, also the same error.